# rAmCharts Scattered plot with Upper and lower confidence interval around Fitted values

Tags: javascript, r, amcharts

I am trying to create a Scatter plot with rAmCharts with a Trend line that will also include the Upper and Lower Confidence interval for Fitted values.

Below is my Data along with the underlying Confidence interval :

```
Data = data.frame(ax = rnorm(50), ay = rnorm(50))
                                            Data = cbind(Data, predict(lm(Data$ay ~ Data$ax - 1), newdata = data.frame(x = Data$ax), interval = 'prediction'))
                                            Data = Data[order(Data$ax), , drop = FALSE]
```

Also, the rAmCharts implementation for above data :

```
amChart_Plot = amXYChart() %>%
                  setDataProvider(dataProvider = Data, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
                  addGraph(xField = "ax", yField = 'ay', bullet = 'round', lineAlpha = 0, bulletAlpha = 0.8, bulletSize = 15) %>%   
                  addGraph(xField = "ax", yField = 'fit', bullet = 'round', lineAlpha = 0.5, bulletAlpha = 0, linetSize = 45, lineColor = '#d202fc') %>%                                                             
                  setBalloon(cornerRadius = 12, textAlign = "left", maxWidth = 1300)

amChart_Plot@valueAxes = list(list(title = paste('X-Axis', sep = ""), 
                            labelFunction = JS("function(value) {return value+'%';}"), position = 'bottom', titleBold = FALSE),
                            list(title = paste('Y-Axis', sep = ""), 
                            labelFunction = JS("function(value) {return value+'%';}"), position = 'left', titleBold = FALSE))   

amChart_Plot
```

As you see, although I am able to create a Trendline with the Fitted values, however couldnt i*nclude the Upper and Lower confidence interval with the Area within that interval can be filled*.

I searched over net, however all the examples I have come across is only to add the Trend line.

Any pointer how to fill the Area within the Upper and lower confidence interval for Fitted values will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

```
library(rAmCharts)
library(dplyr)
library(htmlwidgets)
set.seed(11223344)
Data = data.frame(ax = rnorm(50), ay = rnorm(50))
Data = cbind(Data, predict(lm(Data$ay ~ Data$ax - 1), 
                   newdata = data.frame(x = Data$ax), interval = 'prediction'))
Data = Data[order(Data$ax), , drop = FALSE]

# Create a data set with the coordinates of the border around the area
Data2 <- data.frame(
           x = c(Data$ax[1],Data$ax,rev(Data$ax)), 
           y = c(Data$lwr[1],Data$upr,rev(Data$lwr))
         )
# Put variables of "Data" into "Data2" (and fill with NAs)
Data2$ax <- c(Data$ax, rep(NA,nrow(Data2)-nrow(Data)))
Data2$ay <- c(Data$ay, rep(NA,nrow(Data2)-nrow(Data)))
Data2$fit <- c(Data$fit, rep(NA,nrow(Data2)-nrow(Data)))

amChart_Plot <- amXYChart() %>%
    setDataProvider(dataProvider = Data2, keepNA = TRUE) %>%
    addGraph(xField = "ax", yField = "ay", bullet = 'round', lineAlpha = 0, 
             bulletAlpha = 0.8, bulletSize = 15) %>%   
    addGraph(xField = "ax", yField = "fit", bullet = 'round', lineAlpha = 0.5, 
             bulletAlpha = 0,  lineThickness = 4, lineColor = '#d202fc') %>%    
    addGraph(xField = "x", yField = "y", bullet = 'round', bulletColor="transparent", 
             lineAlpha = 0.1, fillAlphas = 0.1, linetSize = 45, lineColor = '#0000FF') %>%
    setBalloon(cornerRadius = 12, textAlign = "left", maxWidth = 1300)

amChart_Plot@valueAxes = list(
    list(title = paste('X-Axis', sep = ""), 
         labelFunction = JS("function(value) {return value+'%';}"), 
         position = 'bottom', titleBold = FALSE),
    list(title = paste('Y-Axis', sep = ""), 
          labelFunction = JS("function(value) {return value+'%';}"), 
          position = 'left', titleBold = FALSE)
    )     
amChart_Plot
```

[image]